# What should an XML parser do on encountering a bad encoding= value?

Tags: xml, character-encoding

Shown here in hexdump form so there is no ambiguity.

```
00000000  3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 65 6e  63 6f 64 69 6e 67 3d 22  |<?xml encoding="|
00000010  55 54 46 2d 31 36 22 3f  3e 0d 0a 3c 78 6d 6c 3e  |UTF-16"?>..<xml>|
00000020  48 69 3c 2f 78 6d 6c 3e                           |Hi</xml>|
```

What should an XML parser do if it encounters a really bad encoding= value?

Does the answer change if the document has a valid BOM for some other encoding than the one declared in `<?xml` at the start?

I got here through trying to figure out how to pass XML documents through an link that can't process UTF-16, but can process almost any other encoding. When it comes to encodings, UTF-16 is the oddball, so I'm not much surprised at this.

Comment: I normally see the xml passed inside html using <![CDATA[]]>.  Html is better at with different encodings.

Comment: @jdweng: That's only because browsers auto-sense and are smart enough to ignore a blatently wrong META tag.

Comment: HTML is more secure, can handle binary data, and get through firewalls/virus checker better.  The question really is "pass xml document through a link".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [**W3C XML Recommendation**](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/), specifically the *[Encoding Declaration](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#d0e4623)* section, more specifically the following paragraph:

> In the absence of information provided by an external transport
>   protocol (e.g. HTTP or MIME), **it is a [fatal error](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-fatal) for an entity
>   including an encoding declaration to be presented to the XML processor
>   in an encoding other than that named in the declaration**, or for an
>   entity which begins with neither a Byte Order Mark nor an encoding
>   declaration to use an encoding other than UTF-8. Note that since ASCII
>   is a subset of UTF-8, ordinary ASCII entities do not strictly need an
>   encoding declaration.

(**Bold** added for emphasis.)

Comment: Hmmm. I've seen <?xml encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> in the wild.

Comment: Nothing mentioned precludes use of any character set listed in [*Official Names for Character Sets*](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml), which includes ISO-8859-1.  If you're suggesting that you've seen contradictions between declared and actual character sets, I think the sentiment of your [earlier comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34322793/what-should-an-xml-parser-do-on-encountering-a-bad-encoding-value/34325571?noredirect=1#comment56389076_34322793) applies: Browsers are often forgiving, arguably too forgiving at times.